# Angular - Save submit button did not save into the database

Tags: angular, api

I am using Angular 7 and Laravel 5.8 for an application. Laravel as the backend and Angular as the frontend. When I clicked on the submit button in Angular, nothing happens.

I tried to console it, but nothing was found. I tested it in POSTMAN and everything is okay.

Laravel Backend

```
    public function returnResponse($success, $data, $errorCode = 0, $message = false) {
        $response = array();
        $response['success'] = $success;
        $response['message'] = isset($message) ? $message : '';
        if ($errorCode) {
            $response['errorCode'] = isset($errorCode) ? $errorCode : 0;
        }
        $response['data'] = $data;
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }

    public function createClientQuote(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'client_name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required',
                    'phone' => 'required',
                    'business_name' => 'required',
                    'truck_required' => 'required',
                    'quote_origin' => 'required',
                    'quote_destination' => 'required',
                    'commodity' => 'required',  
                    'weight' => 'required',
                    'loading_date' => 'required',                                     
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->returnResponse(false, ['error' => $validator->errors()], 1, 'Invalid Quote Data');
        }
        $input = $request->all();

        $success = array();
        $clientquote = new ClientQuote;

                $mainData = array();
                $mainData['to'] = $input['email'];
                $mainData['from'] = "noblemfd@gmail.com";
                $mainData['subject'] = "Quote";
                $mainData['content'] = "You have successfully sent a Quote, we will get back to you. Thanks";
                $this->mailSend($mainData);
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['client_name'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['email'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['phone'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['business_name'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['truck_required'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['quote_destination'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['commodity'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['weight'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['loading_date'];
        $clientquote->save();
        return $this->returnResponse(true, array(), 0, 'Client added successfully.');
    }
```

Angular - client-quote.service.ts

```
  createClientQuote(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/createClientQuote', data);
  }
```

client-quote.component.ts

```
    export class ClientQuoteLandingComponent implements OnInit {

     quoteModel: any = {};

     constructor(
      private clientQuoteService: ClientQuoteService, private toastr: ToastrService,
      private router: Router,
      @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,
      private route: ActivatedRoute
     ) {

     }

      ngOnInit() {
      }


      onCreateQuote(quoteform: any) {
        if (!quoteform.valid) { // return false if form not valid
         return false;
       }
        this.clientQuoteService.createClientQuote(this.quoteModel)
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (!response['success']) {
            this.toastr.error(response['message']);
            return false;
          }
          this.toastr.success(response['message']);
          quoteform.reset();
          quoteform.resetForm();
        },
        error => {
          this.toastr.error(error);
        }
       );
     }

    numberOnly(event): boolean {
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
     return false;
     }
     return true;

    }

    }
```

client-quote.component.html

```
                <form class="frmcreatequote" name="createquote" #quoteform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreateQuote(quoteform);" novalidate>

                <aw-wizard #wizard [navBarLayout]="'large-empty-symbols'">
                  <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Personal Details'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '&#xf0b1;', fontFamily: 'FontAwesome' }">
                    <div class="centered-content">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="client_name">Full Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client_name" placeholder="Full Name" name="client_name" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.client_name" #client_name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : client_name.invalid && ((client_name.dirty || client_name.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
                          <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="client_name.invalid && ((client_name.dirty || client_name.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="client_name.errors?.required" class="alert alert-danger">Full Name is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="business_name">Business Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="business_name" placeholder="Business Name" name="business_name" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.business_name" #business_name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : business_name.invalid && ((business_name.dirty || business_name.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
                          <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="business_name.invalid && ((business_name.dirty || business_name.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="business_name.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Business Name is required.</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "(999) 999-9999"' data-mask id="phone" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.phone" #phone="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : phone.invalid && ((phone.dirty || phone.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="phone.invalid && ((phone.dirty || phone.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                              <!-- <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="phone.errors?.required" class="alert alert-danger">Phone Number is required.</div> -->
                              <!-- <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="email.errors?.email">Email must be a valid email address</div> -->
                            </div>  
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                              </div>
                              <!-- <input class="form-control" placeholder="example@email.com" type="email" > -->
                              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.email" #email="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : email.invalid && ((email.dirty || email.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>                         
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="email.invalid && ((email.dirty || email.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="email.errors?.required" class="alert alert-danger">Email is required.</div>
                            <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="email.errors?.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
                          </div>   
                          </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-12">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                              <label for="address">Address</label>
                              <!-- <input class="form-control" placeholder="Address" type="text" ngx-google-place (onSelect)="onAddressChange($event)"> -->
                              <!-- <input class="form-control" placeholder="Address" type="text" ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='options' #placesRef="ngx-places" (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)"/> -->
                              <input class="form-control" placeholder="address" type="text" id="address" name="address" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.address" #address="ngModel" >
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                          <br>

                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" awNextStep> Next ></button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  </aw-wizard-step>
                  <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Transaction Details'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '&#xf085;', fontFamily: 'FontAwesome' }">
                    <div class="centered-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <label for="quote_origin">Origin</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quote_origin" placeholder="Origin" name="quote_origin" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.quote_origin" #quote_origin="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : quote_origin.invalid && ((quote_origin.dirty || quote_origin.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
                              <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="quote_origin.invalid && ((quote_origin.dirty || quote_origin.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="quote_origin.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Origin is required.</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <label for="quote_destination">Destination</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quote_destination" placeholder="Destination" name="quote_destination" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.quote_destination" #quote_destination="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : quote_destination.invalid && ((quote_destination.dirty || quote_destination.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
                              <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="quote_destination.invalid && ((quote_destination.dirty || quote_destination.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="quote_destination.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Destination is required.</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                           </div>
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                              <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label for="commodity">Commodity</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="commodity" placeholder="Commodity" name="commodity" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.commodity" #commodity="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : commodity.invalid && ((commodity.dirty || commodity.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
                                <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="commodity.invalid && ((commodity.dirty || commodity.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                  <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="commodity.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Commodity is required.</div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label for="truck_required">Required Truck(s)</label>
                                <input type="text" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" class="form-control" id="truck_required" placeholder="1,2,3..." name="truck_required" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.truck_required" #truck_required="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : truck_required.invalid && ((truck_required.dirty || truck_required.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
                                <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="truck_required.invalid && ((truck_required.dirty || truck_required.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                  <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="truck_required.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Required Truck(s) is required.</div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                  <label for="weight">Weight (in KG)</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weight" placeholder="1000,2500,3100..." name="weight" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.weight" #weight="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : weight.invalid && ((weight.dirty || weight.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
                                  <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="weight.invalid && ((weight.dirty || weight.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="weight.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Commodity Weight is required.</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="loading_date">Loading Date</label>
                                    <div class="input-group date">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker">
                                      </div>
                                </div>
                               </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                   <div class="col-xs-12">
                                   <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                                   <input class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" type="text" id="comment" name="comment" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.comment" #comment="ngModel" >
                                </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                             <br>
                             <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                   <button style="margin:5px" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" awPreviousStep> < Previous</button> 
                                  <button style="margin:5px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" awNextStep> Next ></button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                  </aw-wizard-step>
                  <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Complete'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '&#xf00c;', fontFamily: 'FontAwesome' }">
                    <div class="centered-content">
                      <div>
                        Content: Step 3
                      </div>
                      <br>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                      <div class="btn-group">
                        <button style="margin:5px"  type="button" class="btn btn-warning" awPreviousStep>< Previous</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" > Send Quote</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                  </aw-wizard-step>
                </aw-wizard>

              </form>
```

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" > Send Quote</button>
```

When I clicked on the submit button, I expected it to save into the database, but nothing happen.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hello midowu. My english is very poor, but i don´t see the route in larave, In your browser, are there errors in console? I don´t see that you create **CORS** in Laravel **middleware** , and don´t see you seend headers in your call. `createClientQuote(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/createClientQuote', data,{headers: headers});
  } ` you need declared this header with a property content-type type json,form, url ,etc.. I hope to be helpfull

Comment: I created CORS in Laravel. This is the route in Laravel  
   Route::get('createClientQuote','ApiController@createClientQuote');

Comment: you have add **CORS** in your controller?   When you try create the clientQuote, you don´t see any errors in browser ( console).